# Modular javascript event library

Tags: javascript, events, dom-events, dom4

I want a small library that does [DOM4 events](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#events). Failing that a sensible subset of [DOM3 events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/) will do.

Does it exist?

Answers that are not valid

- Use large framework X (jQuery, mootools, prototype, etc)
- Some library that doesn't work in IE8
- Libraries that do not allow for both capture and bubble phases.

It only needs to work in IE8

Comment: [My DOM-shim](https://github.com/Raynos/DOM-shim/blob/b63f84b48c55edf69fd36b20118a8136b56564bb/src/ie8/interfaces/EventTarget.js) has made an attempt at implementing `EventTarget`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can say with reasonable confidence the answer is *no*.  There was [talk](http://old.nabble.com/DOMe-ecmascript-library-for-DOM-3-events-td28923445.html) of a library called **DOMe** for level 3 events, but I don't think it ever got off the ground.

There are several reasons why such a library would be difficult:

- IE 8's never even heard of event capturing (even though it was originally Microsoft's idea).
- Mutation events are virtually impossible to shim.
- `KeyboardEvent` would be a nightmare to get right because of [Key Values](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#keys-keyvalues), I'm not sure it's even feasible to attempt it.  This is because `keyCode` can vary between input languages.

With all that in mind, *small library* is starting to sound a little too optimistic.  To get around the first problem, you'd need to implement the entire event model by binding a handler to an original event that bubbles and pseudo-refire the event on handlers attached via your shimmed methods, starting on the document and working your way to the original event's `srcElement`/`target` and back again.

The simplest solution is probably another reason a shim doesn't exist, most people just shim the events they need, if possible, and try to avoid the need for capturing.

Comment: Event capturing is easy, emulate the entire event system, just use IE8's `attachEvent` and `detachEvent` to hook it into your own event system. Mutation events are easy, don't implement them, they are deprecated. "Key Values" sound like a difficult problem.